# problem with NextAuth and Next.js to a Dynamic Route like this "http://localhost:3000/profile/%5B%5D"

Tags: next.js, fetch, prisma, next-auth, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm currently developing a website using Next.js, and I'm utilizing the Next.js App router. I've integrated NextAuth for handling logins, and so far, user creation and login are working perfectly.

However, I've encountered an issue when setting up a redirection after login. Currently, when I click the login button, my fetch redirects me directly to the "/profile" page. However, I would like to create a dynamic route to redirect the user to something like "/profile/[userName]".

To achieve this, I've created a file "[userName]" in the "pages" directory with a "page.jsx". The idea is that upon login, it should take me to "/profile/[userName]". However, the problem is that it either always redirects me to "http://localhost:3000/profile", or it directs me to "http://localhost:3000/profile/%5B%5D" when I use the following code in my fetch:
`router.push(`/profile/[${userSlug}]`);`
I've also tried the following version, but it doesn't work either:
`router.push(`/profile/${String(userSlug)}`);`

Can you help me understand why the redirection isn't working as expected and how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance for your assistance!"

**this is my loginPage:**

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

import { useFormik } from "formik";
import Image from "next/image";

import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function Login({ params }) {
  const session = useSession();
  const { status } = useSession();
  let slug;
  const isAuthenticated = status === "Authenticated";

  const userName = session.data?.user?.name;
  const userSlug =
    userName && userName.includes(" ")
      ? userName.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase()
      : "";

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return redirect("/");
  }
  const router = useRouter();
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  console.log("SESSION: ", session);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      email: formik.values.email,
      password: formik.values.password,
      redirect: false,
    });
    if (result.error == null) {
      console.log("fetch", slug);
      router.push(`/profile/${String(userSlug)}`);
    }
    setError(result.error);
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    onSubmit: handleSubmit,
  });

  return (
    <section className="mt-8">
      <h1 className="text-center text-4xl mb-4">Login</h1>
      <form
        className="flex flex-col max-w-xs mx-auto"
        onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
        // onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        {error && <div className="text-red-500">{error}</div>}
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="email"
          value={formik.values.email}
          // value={email}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          // onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={formik.values.password}
          // value={password}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          // onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <div className="my-4 text-center text-gray-500">
          or login with provider
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          alt="google logo"
          onClick={() => signIn("google", { callbackUrl: "/" })}
          className="flex gap-4 justify-center"
        >
          <Image src={"/google.png"} alt={""} width={24} height={24} />
          Login with google
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**this is my auth route.js**

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// export default NextAuth(authOptions);

const handler = NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        name: { label: "Name", type: "text" },
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "test@example.com",
        },
      },
      // ...

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Check to see if email and password are valid
        if (
          !credentials.email ||
          !credentials.password ||
          credentials.email === "" ||
          credentials.password === ""
        ) {
          throw new Error("Email and password are required");
        }

        // Check to see if the user exists
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user) {
          throw new Error("User not found");
        }

        // Check to see if the password matches
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );

        if (!passwordMatch) {
          throw new Error("Incorrect password");
        }

        // Return the user object if everything is valid
        return user;
      },

      // ...
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**What I Tried and Expected (Additional Information):**
In my attempts to resolve the redirection issue, I took the following actions:

1. I tried converting the `userSlug` variable to a string and used it in the route:

   ```
   router.push(`/profile/${String(userSlug)}`);
   ```

   However, this did not address the problem, and the redirection issue persisted.
2. As a test, I directly set a username in the route:

   ```
   router.push("/profile/john");
   ```

   Surprisingly, this worked as expected and redirected me to "http://localhost:3000/profile/john."
3. I experimented with different variations, including removing the square brackets from the dynamic route:

   ```
   router.push(`/profile/${userSlug}`);
   ```

   Unfortunately, this also resulted in a direct redirection to "http://localhost:3000/profile" without considering the dynamic value.
4. I deleted the "page.js" file from the "profile" directory, but this did not bring about any changes in the redirection behavior.

Answer (score 0):

use router.push() when you know that the user was authenticated in

```js
if (isAuthenticated) {
    router.push(`profile/${userSlug}`)
  }
```